# How to add an array to this google app script?

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I'd like to call this custom formula in Google sheets +100 times. Can I add an array to this script?

```js
function GOOGLEMAPS(start_adress,end_adress) {
  
  
  var mapObj =  Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_adress);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_adress);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();
  
 
  var meters = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"];
  var distance = meters/1000;
  
  return distance;
      
  
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  What do you want the array to do?

Comment: I made a custom function to calculate the distance between 2 locations. I want to make this calculation numerous times.  In order to avoid exceeding the data  quota I hoped to solve this with an array. Anyway my question is answer bij Rubén. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 3):

You might add an array but this could easily lead to exceed the quota of the number calls being done in a short period of time, also it could exceed the maximum execution time for a custom function (30 seconds) so the advise is to not do that when using the Map Service.

Anyway, you could send an array to a custom function by useing a `A1:B2` style reference justlimit the number of distances to be calculated in order to prevent the errors mentioned above.

```
function GOOGLEMAPS(arr) {
 var output = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 

  var start_address = arr[i][0];
  var end_adress = arr[i][1];

  var mapObj =  Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_adress);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_adress);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();
  
 
  var meters = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"];
  var distance = meters/1000;
  
  output.push([distance]);
      
  }
  return output;
}
```

Resource

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions

Related

- [Errors When Calculating Distance Between Two Addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30804763/1595451)
- [Google Sheets JSON Error: "Service invoked too many times for one day:"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37759719/1595451)

Other related

- [Google Apps Script - How to get driving distance from Maps for two points in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31799521/1595451)